# Looking for a SASS/SCSS/Less library for non-ASP .NET Core app

Tags: css, .net-core, sass, less

I'm working on a cross-platform command line app that converts a user's text files into HTML output (similar to Markdown), and I want to provide the users an option to customize the output style with SASS/Less. Is there any CSS preprocessor/compiler library out there that I can use to compile stylesheets at runtime?

LibSASS requires installing things on Linux, which I'm trying to avoid because this needs to be a simple "one-click, run anywhere" utility without any dependencies apart from .NET Core. If I remember correctly, it also had conflicts when trying to import multiple platform NuGet packages in the same project.

I started with [dotless](https://github.com/dotless/dotless) but I've already stumbled on like 3 serious bugs and that project hasn't been updated since 2018 so I don't think they're getting fixed anytime soon. And I don't want to tie my project to a dead library for a pretty central functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [SharpScss](https://github.com/xoofx/SharpScss) is what I'm looking for. By adding

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64;linux-x64;osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to the project file, the SASS parsing runs in both Windows and Linux (haven't tested on OSX) without having to install or configure anything.